# Is there any difference between Oracle's Java and Java used in Android?

Tags: java, android, programming-languages

I have started to program in Java SE recently, and I noticed from many articles and heard from rumours, that Android applications are developed in Java, or in a language similar to Java.

I noticed also that there are other packages to use, because we have to develop for mobile devices.

Until recently, I was never interested in mobile devices and applications, like the Android OS, but now I understood that this is the future, and a great chance of a job.

My question is: if in the near future, I want to develop something in Android, do I have  to learn a different Java language than I used to program now?

Are there a lot of differences, programmatically, between the Java language and Java used in Android?

Thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is no difference between Java and Oracle's Java . It's called Oracle Java because Oracle owns Java. You can develop the Android application using Core Java.

If you know Core Java then you just need to learn the Android SDK to develop Android applications.

Refer this site for learning Android: [Android Developer Site](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals.html) .

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Yes, I know Java was developed by Sun, and now owned by Oracle, with no diff ;) Never heard the name "Core Java", maybe is http://www.velocityreviews.com/forums/t124719-what-is-core-java.html right?

Comment: Core Java has to do with the basic package of Java objects that are typically used for general desktop applications

Read more: http://wiki.answers.com/Q/What_is_difference_between_core_Java_and_advanced_Java#ixzz1RbbXYNB0

Comment: Thank you. I understood better what Core Java is with this link. ;)

Answer (score 8):

Android applications are written (most of the times) in Java. This is a pure java with additional libraries, minus some of the UI libraries (such as swing). It even compiles to class files, and then converted to .dex files which are the executable for the Dalvik VM.

If you already know Java, you'll need to learn the usage of the Android SDK and operating system, not a new programming language.

See some basics at the [Android developer site](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals.html)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. ;) The Dalvik VM, I think, is the equivalent for the JVM, right? Thanks for the link.

Comment: Yes. The Dalvik VM is the virtual machine of Android, which should be optimized for android devices.

Answer (score 2):

The omission of many of the base class libraries (eg those that are in the javax namespace) means that while the language is identical, many libraries written in Java will not work out of the box.

Comment: I understood. Like the user MByD answered, this is pure java minus some base class libraries, like swing, that's in the javax namespace, also called Advanded Java. Thank you! ;)

Comment: Why not just include javax in your app?